# NSDictionary - UI label error

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, nsdictionary

I have this two members:

```
int counter;
IBOutlet UILabel *count;
```

and I'm using them as followed:

```
- (void)saveCount {
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [dict mutableCopy] ;
    [mDict setObject:@(count) forKey:@(itemIndex)] ;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mDict forKey:@"saveCount"] ;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] ;
}
```

this line:

```
[mDict setObject:@(count) forKey:@(itemIndex)] ;
```

is giving me an error - "Illegal type 'UILabel' used in a boxed expression".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think since UILabel is already an object, you do not need to wrap it around "@()"

Comment: don't use `int` for counter. int has negative side, count doesn't have. also, `int` is a system dependent thing, use NSInteger instead. So, after all, use NSUInteger for counts in objective-c

Comment: @dicobraz use `count` without `@()` around. just blank `count`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store the Label itself in user defaults, instead of the value of the label. You can store the `NSString` value of the label with `count.text`. You can also store number values with `count.text.doubleValue` or `count.text.integerValue`.

The key you are saving with must also be an `NSString`. A simple conversion based on your itemIndex variable can be done like so:

```
[mDict setObject:count.text forKey:@(itemIndex).stringValue];
```

EDIT: Changed to account for dasblinkenlight's comment

Comment: It looks like OP wanted a different behavior altogether: `itemIndex` looks like a suitable name for a variable of numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, it can be inferred that, upon some "save" action, you would like to save the value in the "UILabel".

As I see:
 - When we are interested in saving the "UILabel" content, then it would be better to take the "UILabel-text" and store it, against some key. i.e. something like;

> [mDict setObject:@(count.text) forKey:@(itemIndex)] ;

is there any specific reason, for using "UILabel" object as value inside the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults can't store "non-property" objects, which means you can't store something like UILabel(UIView) or something like UIImage in a dictionary and save it in defaults. NSUserDefaults can store "properties" like NSData, NSString, NSNumber etc… so you should really put the text of the label in the NSUserDefaults